# Crystal Report Application Crashes after created windows intstaller in setUp and Deployment in Vs 2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have created windows form application and it has a print option , the report should be crystal report . `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll` i am using for created the report.

**Scenario:**

> 1)The application works fine when run inside the Vs 2010.Able to print
>   the report. 2) If i close the vs and Go to Debug folder and run the
>   application , its working fine and able to create the Report.

**Problem:**

> 3) Application Crashes while Install the application and when click
>   the print option has crashed ,all other modules are working fine.The
>   problem happens for report.

So How to create a installable Windows application without crashing crystal report.

This is the method i have used to create the Installable file.[image]

App crash when click `print` option.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check:

> 1. crystal report runtime version.
> 2. OS 32bit or 64bit.
> 3. visual c++ redistributable.

Comment: I suggest install CR Report 32bit and 64bit runtime if you are using 64bit OS.